# Removing intermediate terms from a $10^{\text{th}}$-degree polynomial

Tags: polynomials, factorization, tschirnhaus-transformations

When given a tenth degree polynomial
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{10} a_n x^n$$
I wish to compute an inverse via the [Lagrange inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) to produce a generalized hypergeometric sum similar to a [Bring ultradical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical) or [Kampe de Feriet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamp%C3%A9_de_F%C3%A9riet_function).

I believe that I have been able to compute an inverse for a function of the form
$$\hat{f}(y)= y^{10} + \sum_{n \in S} b_n y^n + b_0$$
Where $S\subset\{1,...,9\}$ contains no more than three elements. For example, $S = \{1, 5, 6\}$.

Tschirnhaus asserted that two of the intermediate terms for an $n^{\text{th}}$ degree polynomial could be removed by means of his transformation in his [original paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/844076.844078). I am also aware, that a higher order substitution must be made to convert a polynomial into Bring-Jerrard form.

**Question:** Is there a substitution via a rational function $y(x)$ that could convert $f(x)$ to $\hat{f}(y)$?

I was hoping to express $y(x)$ as a $5^{\text{th}}$ degree polynomial, which would allow me to recover $x$ using Bring ultradicals. I had hoped then, that I could  nest a Bring radical (in terms of one variable) inside of a hypergeometric series (in terms of four variables) as opposed to examining one higher order hypergeometric series.